# Equivalent of HTML 5 data attributes for android views

Tags: java, android, xml, android-view

Is there a way I can store/retrieve arbitrary values from a view, similar to HTML5 data attributes?
This way, I can have a view call generic `onClick()` methods and the method can retrieve the related data.

e.g:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="setCountry"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_flag_germany" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="setCountry"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_flag_france" />
...
```

I would like to be able to retrieve a value from the one that got clicked.

```
public void setCountry(View v){
     //retrieve data somehow
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `View`'s [tag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3atag) property. It is intented for that purpose.

For example:

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick="setCountry"
android:src="@drawable/ic_flag_germany" 
android:tag="Germany" />
```

...

```
public void setCountry(View v) {
    System.out.println(v.getTag());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Derive from ImageView, add a member variable "country" and accessor methods. Then you can reference your class in the layout file:

```
<com.foo.MyImageView ... />
```

Or use the `tag` property. It lets you attach an arbitrary object to a control, but there's no type safety, and no accessor methods with appropriate names. You can specify a string tag right there in the XML file.

Or use some kind of mapping from control ID to country.